# duplicate rows in many to many relation EF 5.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many, insert-update

I have this two tables

```
[Table("Designs")]
public class Design
{
    [Key]
    public Int64 ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
[Table("Tags")]
public class Tag
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Design> Designs { get; set; }
}
```

this is my context

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            this.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Design>().HasMany(m => m.Tags).WithMany(m => m.Designs).Map(m => { m.MapLeftKey("DesignID"); m.MapRightKey("TagID"); m.ToTable("DesignsToTags"); });
        }
```

there are some tags

[image]

and this is the cross table

[image]

I try to update tags for design

```
    public Design EditDesign(Design design, int[] newTags)
    {
        var entry = ctx.Entry(design);

        entry.Collection(m => m.Tags).Load();


        design.Tags = newTags.Select(m => ctx.Tags.Find(m)).ToList();

        entry.State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
        ctx.SaveChanges();

        return design;
    }
```

and this code adds duplicate values in **Tags** table (ID == 3 and 16 are same), but in **DesignsToTags** table everything is OK

[image]
[image]

How can I prevent adding duplicate values??

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the problem

I need to include Tags when get the design

```
var design = ctx.Designs.Include(m => m.Tags).Single(m => m.ID == model.Id);
```

instead of

```
var design = ctx.Designs.Find(model.Id);
```

and everything works perfectly.